# how to sshfs login as sudo user

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, mount, sudo

I need to mount an external shared resource using `sshfs`. I have setup SSH authentication between my PC and the server using a local user (non-root) and it works like a charm using the following command:

```
sshfs rperez@<server_ip>:/home/rperez/shared -p 2051 ~/shared -o auto_cache,reconnect
```

Now I need to share the mounted resource with a Docker container as a volume but *apparently* this is not possible without run the command above using `sudo`. This is the output for run the command above as `sudo`:

```
$ sudo sshfs rperez@<server_ip>:/home/rperez/shared -p 2051 ~/shared -o auto_cache,reconnect
[sudo] password for rperez: 
fuse: bad mount point `/home/rperez/shared': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

And the mount point turns into red with `?` as first character and becomes non accessible meaning `?shared` (red because I am seeing from mc`.

I've tried to setup SSH authentication with `sudo` but apparently is [not possible](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27026#issuecomment-250687333) as per the answer on [this post](https://superuser.com/a/492441/309325). I have read a few ones about this ([3](https://superuser.com/questions/916959/why-must-i-use-sudo-for-ssh-public-key-authentication-to-work), [4](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9308/sudo-password-when-authenticating-via-passwordless-ssh), [5](https://superuser.com/questions/309292/how-to-ssh-into-a-server-as-sudo-from-application), [6](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72689/ssh-key-auth-but-still-need-password-for-sudo)) topic but I can't get this to work.

Any advice? What I am missing here?

**Update**:

Following the suggestion from @Xaloroues I have running the following commands:

```
$ sudo mkdir shared
$ sudo sshfs rperez@<server_ip>:/home/rperez/shared -p 2051 /mnt/shared -o auto_cache,reconnect
rperez@<server_ip> password:
```

The mount command works but I can't access the mounted resource. I have run the following command and see the output:

```
$ sudo stat /mnt/shared
[sudo] password for rperez: 
  File: 'shared'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 32h/50d Inode: 1           Links: 1
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1041/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1038/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2016-09-30 10:27:28.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2016-09-21 15:20:20.000000000 -0400
Change: 2016-09-21 15:20:20.000000000 -0400
 Birth: -
```

Also see this pic about how the mounted folder looks like:

[image]

The permissions before mount the shared resources seems to be fine:

```
$ ls -la /mnt/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Sep 30 10:35 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 4096 Sep 30 08:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Sep 30 10:35 shared
```

So, what's wrong?

Comment: With 755 permissions, anyone should be able to read `/mnt/shared`.  After the mount, what are the results of the same command? (`ls -ld /mnt`).  The 'UNKNOWN' in UID and GID in the `stat` command results.is due to the fact that NFS uses UID and GID to determine ownership and group membership, and UID and GID are not automatically sync'd between systems.  There are MANY ways of syncing them, with varying degrees of complexity, none are both easy and automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root does not have permissions to the mountpoint.  Choose one outside your profile.  The best place per [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) would be a mount point under /mnt.

Comment: That's not true at all and it it's then something else is wrong because is not working for me, check my edit on OP

Comment: Log in as a sudo user on a Linux box (`someuser` for our example).  Run `sudo su` (without the usual -).  The result is you switch to root but do not change environment.  You're still in /user/someuser pwd.  Now run `ls` and tell me again how I'm wrong.  Unless you've modified the permissions or ownership of /user, root cannot go into individual users folders as root.  Root can switch to a user and then go in.  Root can take ownership and then go in.  Root can change permissions to +r on the others bit and then go in.  But root can't read users' home folders directly without modification.

Comment: You're running a sudo command to run as root.  That command tells root to mount an external share to a place where root has no direct permissions.  So it fails.  With the error code you mention.